# pip does not exist or could not be executed within virtualenv

Tags: python, macos, flask, pip, virtualenv

When trying to use pip to install flask within a virtual environment, I get the following error:

```
>(venv)username@Username-MacBook-Air ~/G/L/flaskTest> pip install Flask
>Failed to execute process '/Users/User/Google Drive/flaskTest/venv/bin/pip'. Reason:
>The file '/Users/username/Google Drive/flaskTest/venv/bin/pip' does not exist or could not         be executed.
```

Is there any reason why this is happening?

Comment: Does the file exist? If not, that's why it's happening.

Comment: Check your permissions

Comment: Try to create a clean new `venv`

Answer (score 9):

Just had the same problem, which led me here. I had just created a new virtual environment and got that error. Like you, I had an ancestor directory with a space in it. After renaming the directory to eliminate the space, everything worked fine. (Someday I'll track down the bug!) Try changing "Google Drive" to "google_drive" or "GoogleDrive", etc.

Comment: I had space in my Python distribution path. Eliminating it helped, despite I still have spaces in my VE path.

Comment: Had to rename my `Google Drive` folder, so I named mine `GDrive`. To do this, close the Google Drive app, rename your folder, re-open the app, wait for it to throw a fit about not being able to find the folder, click Locate and point it to the new folder. Done!

Answer (score -1):

First, try install a new and clean virtual environment.

If not work, try installing pip, with `easy_install pip`